# Get item of ListActivity

Tags: java, android

`ListActivity` always has corresponding `ListView` element, right? So, has it any method to get list item by index or I have to get `ListView` instance manually using `findViewById` and get item from it?
**EDIT:**
I want to change text of list item in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go about this is a little different than what you might expect.  Rather than trying to get the view and change its text, you should retrieve the data from your adapter and update it.  After that, you may need to reset the adapter that your ListActivity uses.

To get the adapter, you need to first call `ListActivity.getListAdapter`.  Once you have the `Adapter`, you can call `Adapter.getItem` to get the data at a specific position.

Comment: Please, provide an example of how I can change text of the item at specific position.

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
tv.setText("your text");

Comment: I've added more details to my answer.  I'll try to get around to adding a code sample.  It would help if you posted some of your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously depending on your adapter you'd use different casting etc, but as an example with a ListView in an ListActivity:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" });

    // One, two, three
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // Display "Two" (specified by index with `getItem`).
    Toast.makeText(this, "Element two is: " + (String)getListAdapter().getItem(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```